# How can we edit the current code of quickopen and add new feature of file openning to it?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

we are trying to help with this issue - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196580.

we now incorporated this idea on the /vscode-extension-samples/quickinput-sample and did a demo of it. However, we still got some questions.

Where can we find the code for quick open in the vscode source code? the way we understand it is that the quick open feature is implemented in anythingQuickAccess and is activated through registering it. To achieve the feature request, we modify the function NO_RESULTS_PICK so that the user can be prompted to create the file. The problem is we can display the prompt by doing: label: localize('noAnythingResults', `Create New file (${filter}) (Press 'Enter' to confirm)`). But we are not sure whether we can make this prompt a button so that the user can click it to perform the creation.

Looking forward for your reply. Thank you.

We tried implement that feature inside of the vscode-extension-samples but that can only work as a demo and cannot be complete functional inside of the real vscode application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can we find the code for quick open in the VS Code source code?

- [IQuickInputService](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4b9608ccceba9fee3d5ceb5f76e0b728d7a05068/src/vs/workbench/browser/actions/quickAccessActions.ts#L121)
- [IQuickAccessController](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4b9608ccceba9fee3d5ceb5f76e0b728d7a05068/src/vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput.ts#L526)
- [show](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4b9608ccceba9fee3d5ceb5f76e0b728d7a05068/src/vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickAccess.ts#L58)
- [doShowOrPick](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4b9608ccceba9fee3d5ceb5f76e0b728d7a05068/src/vs/platform/quickinput/browser/quickAccess.ts#L39)